# Retrieving a list of products from stripe .net API and passing it into a SelectList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a user interface in my ASP.NET MVC application for creating plans in stripe. Stripe requires a product ID in order to create a subscription plan, so I need to display a dropdown that lists the available products to the customer.

I have an option where the customer can create products  from a form, and this works perfectly, however, I am having trouble understanding how to pass this into `Html.DropDownList("ProductId")`. I first thought that I would need to save duplicate data in order to achieve this, however, when I tried to do this, I received an error saying that my model  has a value of null, because in my method I am creating two products - one in the api, and one locally - I have changed this back to only use the API.

I've tried more than just this, but this is most recent:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    StripeList<Product> products = new StripeList<Product>();
    ViewBag.Products = new SelectList(products, "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(PlanCreateViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var options = new PlanCreateOptions
        {
            Id = model.Id,
            Amount = model.Amount,
            Currency = model.Currency.ToLower(),
            Interval = model.Interval,
            Product = model.Product,
            IntervalCount = model.IntervalCount,
        };

        var planService = new PlanService();
        await planService.CreateAsync(options);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}

// html helper returns null reference exception 
@Html.DropDownList("Products", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

TL;DR: How can I retrieve a list of the stripe products that display the name of the product, but have the value of the product ID in asp.net mvc5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reviewing the Stripe API, I have managed to list all the products in the dropdown by using the `ProductService()` method. Here is the result:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var service = new ProductService();
    var options = new ProductListOptions { Limit = 5, };
    StripeList<Product> products = service.List(options);
    ViewBag.Products = new SelectList(products, "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}
```